# Kalman Filter with non-contemporaneous sensors

Tags: time-series, kalman-filter

I have spent quite a bit of time on "well-behaved" Kalman filtering problems where, say in a case with 2 sensors, we observe outputs for both sensors at each time step.

However, I am struggling to extend this to a slightly different case, where, say, we run a Kalman update() for each sensor as data comes in (i.e. Kalman update() based on output from only one sensor at a time). An example application for this might be financial trade time series data, where one observes buy and sell trade prices that are some noisy estimate around a true value 'midpoint' for a stock. I'd like to update my Kalman true value estimate on updates on either buy or sell 'sensor' observations.

So state is 2-D vector **x** might be [fair_value, bid_ask_spread_around_fair_value] and observations are 2-D vector **z** = [buy_trade_price, sell_trade_price], but **z** in practice is only a scalar (based on whatever side the trade is).

- Is there a recommended way to adjust the Kalman update() step to accommodate updates on each sensor independently?
- Is there an intuitive way to think about how the resultant covariance matrix of the state variables P is changing with this type of update step?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86332/how-to-handle-incomplete-data-in-kalman-filter